# Error 500 after upgrade to 1.9.3.6 Cronjob failing?

Tags: upgrade, cron

I just did an update from 1.9.3.1 to 1.9.3.6 with the connect manager.
Since then the website is unreachable. It sometimes works if I refresh multiple times but I get an error 500 most of the time.

I checked the log and it seems the cronjob is spamming this error:

> 2017-11-02T12:37:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: shell_exec(): Unable to execute '/bin/sh '/html/my-shop/cron.sh' 'cron.php' -malways 1 \> /dev/null 2\>\&1 \&'  in /html/my-shop/cron.php on line 67

The host is a shared hosting solution so I am not able to see apache or nginx logs. Maybe the cronjob failing is causing the host to shutdown further connections ? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: did you set right permission ?

Comment: I gave 777 to cron.sh and cron.php and it still not working. I completely new to magento sorry..

Comment: you are getting 500 error on site ? Or only cron that is creating the issue ?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes it works if I refresh multiple times. It seems this cron issue is spamming so hard that the host is blocking the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are on shared hosting, may be shell command is not allowed to execute on server.

Add the below line of code

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```

After the below line:

```
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
```

You can set up permission by running the [clean up script](https://github.com/IndiesServices/Magento/blob/master/magento-cleanup.php)

Comment: thanks a lot, it works now. What happens if I leave cron disabled ? I guess a lot of magento functions  will not work ?

Comment: Cron is required otherwise order email, catalog rule stop working

Comment: It did work before the upgrade. Should I do a rollback or is there a fix or a way to debug this ?